# Rxjs how to cache the result of an observable for a given argument?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

In my app I use rxjs and I have a method that looks like this:

```
query<T extends TableRow>(queryString: string, silent = false): Observable<T[]> {
  return this.sqliteService.dbQuery<T>(queryString).pipe(
    tap(val => {
      if (this.configService.debugMode && !silent) {
        console.log(`\n${queryString}`);
        console.log(val);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

My `query` method interlly calls `dbQuery` that queries an sqlite database.

Also, the `query` method is called many times in my app. So I'd like to globally cache the result whenever the `queryString` is the same.

In other words, I'd like the `query` method to avoid calling again `dbQuery` when called with a `queryString` parameter that has been called before, by returning the previously-cached value.

Not sure if this is relevant: my `query` method lives in an Angular singleton service.

Answer (score 3):

First time through, save the remote value to a local cache property with a key that is the query string.

On subsequent requests, return the existing property for the corresponding key.

```js
private cache = {};

query<T extends TableRow>(queryString: string, silent = false): Observable<T[]> {
  if (this.cache.hasOwnProperty(queryString)) {
    return of(this.cache[queryString]);
  }

  return this.sqliteService.dbQuery<T>(queryString).pipe(
    tap(val => {
      this.cache[queryString] = val;

      if (this.configService.debugMode && !silent) {
        console.log(`\n${queryString}`);
        console.log(val);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks @Kurt however I was hoping that there was some rxjs built in for that

Comment: *Something* has to persist the values outside of the function - be it your own subject or an object. Any state stored in the function or reference to an observable created in the function is going to die once the observable returns.

Comment: also, as the `cache` object grows in size, I'm wondering if it will be more efficient at the end

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
private cache: Observable<string>[] = [];

getItem(id: number): Observable<string> {

  if (!this.cache[id]) {
    this.cache[id] = this.query<string>(
      `SELECT column FROM table WHERE id = ${id}`
    ).pipe(shareReplay());
  }

  return this.cache[id];
}
```

Comment: You might want to even use `shareReplay(1)` so that late subscribers only get the latest value and don't get the whole history